# How to access a container from another where both are running on different machine?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-container

I do not have much knowledge about docker networking where I have 2 different containers while they are placed on two different machines. In this scenario, I have **two raspberry pi** where one is a **server** and another is a **client**.

Both use the CoAP protocol to exchange the message(s). Anyway, the client requires the server's ip as a parameter for the client script like --

```
python src/client.py <server_ip>
```

I inspect the server container and got the private ip as --

```
172.18.0.2
```

Here are docker-compose files for server and client --

**docker-compose.yml (server)**

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    build: ./
    image: img_server:v1
    ports: 
      - 5683:5683/udp
    volumes: 
      - ./:/usr/app
    command: ["python", "src/server.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml (client)**

```
version: '3'

services:
  client:
    build: ./
    image: img_client:v1
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: "127.0.0.1"
    ports: 
      - 61616:61616/udp
    volumes: 
      - ./:/usr/app
    command: ["sh", "-c", "python src/client.py $SERVER_IP"]
```

I am unable to establish the connection since the containers (server & client) are running on different machines.

**Question:**  Is it possible to make the connection between the server and the client where both are placed in separate docker daemon (separate machine)? If so then How do I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same as if the services weren't running in Docker: configure the client with the IP address of the physical host running the service.  (Make sure you've published the appropriate `ports:` so they're reachable.)

You should never `docker inspect` a container to find its IP address.  There are many common situations, this one included, where that address is completely useless, and there is always a better way to reach the container.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 basic approaches to this.

First - work like you are not using dockerized applications. Expose ports from your `docker-compose` files and specify ip/hostname of your **host** machines to connect (note - you dont use container's IP in this case - after exposing ports they become available from hosts).

Second - **recommended** - use docker's `overlay` networking to connect you containers all together. Unlike `bridge` mode, `overlay` allows connecting between different docker daemons. This way is better as it provides isolation of your containers from host machines. Overlay networking requires you to create `docker swarm` and connect your containers to it.

Quick man: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/#walkthrough